# How do I prevent a git merge confclit from "eating" changes?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-merge

I screwed up another merge. I had two lines squashed together and missed a minor change on the second line when I took my changes in the above line.

So here's the conflict:

[image: hur]

And here's where I screwed up:
[image: dur]

See the difference? `Awaiting Fulfillment` needed to be lower case.

That's my bad, but that's not my problem/question.

The problem is that when I merge this, *it looks like `Awaiting Fulfillment` was never ever changed.* `git blame` shows the commit before that change, and not my b0rked merge. The diff on the pull request also shows *no changes* to that line.

This has happened to us a few times, and I'm not exactly sure how to catch it. How can I make these bad merges clear and easy to find?

---

Here's what I did to screw this up (my workflow):

1) I make a branch, `permissions`

2) I do work on `permissions`

3) When I'm done, I `git pull master`

4) After fixing the merge conflicts, I push my `permissions` branch and go to GitHub so I can issue a pull request from there; now my team looks at <strike>what I've broken</strike> my new feature

5) We then merge the pull request

This creates the following two problems:

Looking at the merge commit, there's no change on that line. Line 658 is "untouched".

`git blame` doesn't show the conflicting commit that changed it either. It's like it never got changed.

Buried in the pull request, my bad merge can be found, but not when I'm simply browsing the file's history.

---

What I've tried:

I did `git reset --hard` back to the point before I screwed up and fiddled around with `git pull --rebase` and `git rebase master` and `git rebase permissions`. I got through the `git pull --rebase` and ended up with the same problem (the `git blame` is unclear, and the screw up is hard to find). The rebases felt like a death march -- too many changes and I finally gave up.

---

I feel like I'm missing some crucial git concepts here, but I'm not sure where to even start reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make these bad merges clear and easy to find?

In git starting from [2.6.2](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.6.2.txt#L56) you can use `blame --first-parent` to find a change which was in master already, but was reverted by a merge. But to make it work in your case (when the change was reverted already in your branch), you should blame the head of your branch